# npm webpack installation hangs

Tags: webpack

I've tried a couple of things including npm clear cache --force but keeping have this problem.  Have deleted node_modules in project directory before trying webpack installation
Running on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, Version 1803
Node version: 10.13.0
NPM version: 6.4.1
Used the command `npm install webpack --save-dev --verbose`

Hangs when trying to install acorn@5.7.3.  [Here's the output as it hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVsWc.png)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you can't install if you're running the code on a mapped drive.
Moved project over to C drive and it installed.